# Python Multiprocessing - Unexpected Queue Behaviour after Terminating a Process and Restarting it

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a program in python that uses serveral processes, which communicate with each other using Queue objects from the multiprocessing module.

I am now trying to build a "keep alive" function that periodically checks if a certian process is alive, and if it's not - restarts the process. This is in case some error causes the process to crash but it is important to restore the process to maintain the rest of the program.

Right now I don't actually get crashes, but I want to test if this feature works.
So, I start the program (on Windows), then I manually terminate the process through the task manager and let the "keep alive" function restore it.

The problem - the "keep alive" function sucessfully recognizes the process being terminated and restarts it. However, the process fails to use the given Queue again to commuincate.
If I terminate the process by an internal signal in the code, then it is capable to use the Queue normally. This implies that when manually terminating the process something probably happens to the Queue object which I can't figure out.

The question is - How can I sucessfully restart the process after "non gracefull" termination and be able to reuse the Queue again?

Working on Windows 10 with Python 3.11.

I attach here a simplified example.
Basically, a process is started with a given Queue object. The process prints the items it gets from the Queue until it gets "None" and exists.
The "None" object is my internal signaling, otherwise I terminate the process manually from the task manager.
Here is the code:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


class ProcessStarter:

    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
        self.p = Process()
        self.q = q

    def start_p(self):
        if not self.p.is_alive():
            self.p = Process(target=test_func, args=(self.q, ), daemon=True)
            self.p.start()

    def p_alive(self):
        return self.p.is_alive()


def test_func(q: Queue):
    print("Process Started", time.time())
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        print("Got item: ", item)


def keep_alive(ps: ProcessStarter, q: Queue):
    while True:

        if not ps.p_alive():
            print("Starting Process", time.time())
            ps.start_p()
            for i in range(2):
                q.put(i)
            q.put(None)

        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Large memory consuming object to recognize the main process in task manager:
    memory_taker = "a" * 10000000

    q = Queue()
    ps = ProcessStarter(q=q)

    # Start the keep alive cycle:
    keep_alive(ps=ps, q=q)
```

Runnig this code results with the following output:

Starting Process 1690040068.3635035

Process Started 1690040068.4590366

Got item:  0

Got item:  1

Starting Process 1690040069.385648

Process Started 1690040069.4918761

Got item:  0

Got item:  1

Starting Process 1690040070.4156165

Process Started 1690040070.5324962

Got item:  0

Got item:  1

...

And so on...

Running this code while commenting the line "q.put(None)" and manually terminating the process from the task manager, results with the following output:

Starting Process 1690040198.5529332

Process Started 1690040198.649237

Got item:  0

Got item:  1

-- Here I manually terminated the process.

Starting Process 1690040205.5800357

Process Started 1690040205.7073412
...

And that's it, no more output.

As you can see, this time the Queue is not being used as expected.

## Edit

I modified the "process starter" like so:

```
class ProcessStarter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.p = Process()
        self.q = Queue()

    def start_p(self):
        if not self.p.is_alive():
            self.p = Process(target=test_func, args=(self.q, ), daemon=True)
            self.p.start()

    def p_alive(self):
        return self.p.is_alive()

    def make_new_queue(self):
        self.q = Queue()
```

And the keep alive function like so:

```
def keep_alive(ps: ProcessStarter):
    while True:

        if not ps.p_alive():
            print("Starting Process", time.time())
            ps.make_new_queue()
            ps.start_p()
            for i in range(2):
                ps.q.put(i)
            # ps.q.put(None)

        time.sleep(1)
```

Now, after manual termination the new process does get items from the new queue and prints output.

It seems to confirm that something happens to the original Queue object after the non-gracefull termination of the process.

It doesn't yet resolve the issue because the Queue is used by other processes as well and I don't want to re-declare it everytime for every single process.

Perhaps I can recognize somehow that problematic state of the Queue and call some methods to make it usable again?

Comment: seems like you want queue data to persist across multiple invocations of your application.  you can't use the in memory multiprocessing queue as that is not backed by any persistent storage.

Comment: @erik258 - But after I restart the process I put new items in the queue, regardless of what has been there before. When I terminate the sub-process, the main process is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `if item is None` logic, then your Process will always be waiting (blocked) on the statement `q.get()`.  That statement almost certainly involves a operating system call.  When you use the operating system to close the Process ungracefully, who knows what is going to happen?  It is not surprising that the Queue has become unusable.

A much more realistic scenario, and one that I think you should be worried about instead, is that some error in the data (or your code) causes an Exception to be raised in your Process.  The way to handle that is with exception handling, not by periodically polling every Process to see if it has crashed.

This simple demo program handles exceptions and also the case where the `keep_alive` just exits.  There is no need for polling or for a special class.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def test_func(q: Queue):
    def keep_alive():
        print("Process Started", time.time())
        while True:
            item = q.get()
            if item is None:
                raise Exception("Error")
            if item % 5 == 0:
                break
            print("Got item: ", item)
    while True:
        try:
            keep_alive()
        except Exception:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    proc = Process(target=test_func, args=(q,), daemon=True)
    proc.start()
    for i in range(100):
        if i % 4 == 0:
            q.put(None)
        else:
            q.put(i % 5)
        time.sleep(0.25)
```

Output:

```
Process Started 1690111199.7227108
Process Started 1690111199.7227108
Got item:  1
Got item:  2
Got item:  3
Process Started 1690111200.5405762
Process Started 1690111200.791085
Got item:  1
Got item:  2
Process Started 1690111201.542473
Got item:  4
...
```

You might also consider the possibility that if a Process crashes, or raises an Exception, it happened for a reason.  You may not know the reason or understand it, but wouldn't it be better to catch an Exception so you can see what happened, and maybe create an error log?

If your computer starts doing things for no reason, then you're in trouble no matter how you write your code.  If you just restart the Process in such cases, why should it now begin to work?